# GSAP 3 Scroll Trigger on leave animation reverse

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gsap, scrolltrigger

I have used `GSAP 3.0` `ScrollTrigger` in one of my websites everything is working fine but I want my animations to be reversed when leaving the section or div. I know there is a callback call `onLeave` but I am not able to figure out how to use it. I am new to the scroll trigger. I am pasting the code sample for you to understand.

**armor animation config**

```
        let armor = gsap.timeline({

            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: '.armor-animation',
                pin: true,
                pinSpacing: true,
                anticipatePin: .5,
                scrub: 1,
                start: "top 150px",
                end: "+=1500",
                toggleActions: "play reverse none none",
                // scroller: ".smooth-scroll"
                // markers: true,
                onLeave: () => {
                    // armor.from(".layer-1", .8, {
                    //         translateY: 200,
                    //         opacity: 0
                    //     }, .5)
                    // console.log("leave");
                }
            }

        });
```

**armor section animation**

```
        armor.from(".layer-1", .8, {
                translateX: -200,
                opacity: 0
            }, .5)
            .from(".layer-2", .8, {
                translateY: 200,
                opacity: 0
            }, .6)
            .from(".layer-3", .8, {
                translateY: -200,
                opacity: 0
            }, .6)
            .from(".crack-effect", 2, {
                translateY: -200,
                opacity: 0
            }, 2)
            .from(".method h1", 2, {
                translateX: 200,
                opacity: 0
            }, .6);
```

Comment: please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and why it is usually counter productive to do so.

Comment: You can EITHER have your animation wired to the scrollbar (scrub: true) OR have its play state triggered with toggleActions, not both. It wouldn't make much sense to have scrub: true and also make things reverse when you leave the section - see what I mean? It's logically incoherent. If you need more help, the best place for dedicated GSAP/ScrollTrigger support is at https://greensock.com/forums. Happy tweening!

Comment: Hi @Jack sorry for the late reply. I figured that out by myself. I created separate functions and I called each one of them within the scroll trigger callbacks now animations are working but I am facing another issue. If you are within a particular section and if you try refreshing the page then the scroll trigger animations are not re-initializing.  For Example, if you are inside a section with the class name 'ABC' and then if you refresh the page the animations are not happening also the pinned element goes up somewhere. Any solutions would be really appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: It's really tough to troubleshoot blind - the best way to handle this would be to create a minimal demo (see https://greensock.com/demo) and post your question along with the demo in the forums at https://greensock.com/forums. Once we see the demo, I'm sure we'll be able to offer some suggestions.

Comment: Sure I am going to create a demo right away in the GSAP forums. Thanks